# Concurrency in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, concurrency

In my application, two users are alerted, who first click on the alert is who must save the object, but when the two click at the same time, one overwrites the other. I would not allow two users from changing the same data concurrently, how?

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/concurrency-management-in-parse

Comment: Sorry guy, but i don't understand, because my field not is a number, is a ParseObject. So, the user save in a ParseObject field. I could not get any ideas, you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

Define a `PFObject` `objectSaved` that has a counter field. Initialize the counter to 0.
Trigger a `beforeSave` action (see [here](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers)) in cloud code that is executed when one or both users try to save the same object. In the `beforeSave` action, atomically increment the `objectSaved` counter.
If only 1 user tries to save, the counter is now 1. If 2 users try to save at the same time (2 threads), one of them reads a counter value of 1, the other one a value of 2.
The user who got 1 is the first one, and she/he is allowed to execute the save operation. The other one is the second, and its save attempt is aborted with error.
It helps to read once more the link provided by NSNoob.